# Sort elements based on specific classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm trying to order the div based on the `col-md-x`. First `col-md-4` and then `col-md-8`. I tried the sort function of jQuery in this variant:

```js
var divElement = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
  return a.className > b.className;
}

$('.container').append(divElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">col-md-8</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">col-md-4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">col-md-4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 left">col-md-4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">col-md-8</div>
```

However this is not sorting on my `.col-md-x` class but is he sorting on all classes (I think). How could I sort specific on the class `col-md-x`? I tried also `.pop()` and `.split()`, but this is not working in combination with the jQuery `.sort()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var divElement = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) {
 
   return a.className.match(/col-md-(\d)/)[1] - b.className.match(/col-md-(\d)/)[1];
}

$('.container').append(divElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dic class="container">
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">1</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">2</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">3</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 left">4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check my comment below...this is not working anymore!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to write a function that will return the needed class name by it beginning `col-md-`

```js
$(function() {
  var divElement = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

  function sortMe(a, b) {
     return getColMdClassName(a) > getColMdClassName(b);
  }

  $('.container').append(divElement);
});

function getColMdClassName(obj) {
    return $.grep(obj.className.split(" "), function(v, i){
       return v.indexOf('col-md-') === 0;
   }).join();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class='container'>
  <div class="row different col-md-8 left">8</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 right">4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 right">4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 left">4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-8 left">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing text in sort function but need to compare integers. see below function

```js
$(function(){
var divElement = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

$('.container').append(divElement);
});

function sortMe(a, b) {
  var aInt = getInteger(a.className);
  var bInt = getInteger(b.className);
  return aInt > bInt;
}

function getInteger(classNameList)
{
var int = 0;
var classList = classNameList.split(/\s+/);
for (var i = 0; i < classList.length; i++) {
if (classList[i].indexOf('col-md')!=-1) {
    int = parseInt(classList[i].replace('col-md-',''));
}
}
return int;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">8</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 right">4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-4 left">4</div>
<div class="row different col-md-8 left">8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure js variant:

```js
var divs = document.getElementById('divs');

var map = arr => fn => Array.prototype.map.call(arr, fn);

var getN = str => str.substr(str.indexOf('col-md-'), 8).substr(-1);

var res = map(divs.children)(x => x).sort((a, b) => getN(a.className) - getN(b.className));

res.forEach((el, i) => divs.replaceChild(el, divs.childNodes[i]))
```

```html
<div id="divs">
  <div class="row different col-md-8 left">col-md-8</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 right">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 right">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-4 left">col-md-4</div>
  <div class="row different col-md-8 left">col-md-8</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is not working for me on Chrome, please check [this old fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fmnuxe2p/).
But we can enhance the answer:

**HTML (no changes)**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dic class="container">
    <div class="row different col-md-8 left">1</div>
    <div class="row different col-md-4 right">2</div>
    <div class="row different col-md-4 right">3</div>
    <div class="row different col-md-4 left">4</div>
    <div class="row different col-md-8 left">5</div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript (small changes):**

```
var divElement = $('.container').find('.row').sort(sortMe);

function sortMe(a, b) { 
   return a.className.match(/col-md-(\d)/)[1] - b.className.match(/col-md-(\d)/)[1];
}

$('.container').append(divElement);
```

The new fiddle [is here](https://jsfiddle.net/fmnuxe2p/1/).